# C++ sizeof does not work with template

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C2070 - illegal sizeof operand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485025/c2070-illegal-sizeof-operand)

Why doesn't the templated version of the code below compile, whereas the same exact code will compile when the (unused) template is removed?

---

Does not compile:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    static double const vals[];
    int run ();
};

template <typename T>
double const Foo<T>::vals[] = { 1, 2,3 };

template <typename T>
inline
int Foo<T>::run () {
    return sizeof(vals); // error C2070: 'const double []': illegal sizeof operand
}
```

---

Compiles:

```
class Foo {
public:
    static double const vals[];
    int run ();
};

double const Foo::vals[] = { 1, 2,3 };

inline
int Foo::run () {
    return sizeof(vals);
}
```

Comment: It compiles with g++ 4.5 so presumably it's a MS bug.

Comment: GCC [compiles it](http://ideone.com/ajiUkW) allright.

Answer (score 0):

Because Visual Studio is broken.  See: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/759407/can-not-get-size-of-static-array-defined-in-class-template

A possible (untested) workaround would be to use something like this:

```
private:
template<typename T, int size>
int get_array_length(T(&)[size]){return size;}
```

And then use:

```
int Foo::run() {
    return get_array_length(vals) * sizeof(double);
}
```

Comment: If you know it's a duplicate, vote to close for that reason, don't add an answer!

Comment: Sadly the workaround doesnt work `error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'size_t countof(T (&)[size])'`