# compiler error how to track back what cause it

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

How can I track back what caused compiler error in the first place ? I mean which part of my code invoked that error ?

For example, I'm using VS2017 with default compiler and i get following compile error:

```
C2070   'unsigned char []': illegal sizeof operand | type_traits    1227
```

Which points to standard library header `type_traits`, but that's pointless because i have no idea which part of my code cause it so how can i track it back to the original point in my code ?

Right now I see just one option and thats systematicaly commenting parts of my code until I dont get that error. There has to be something to track it.

Comment: Read on. There are a slew of additional notes to the message that eventually lead back to your code.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Not in Visual Studio's Error window

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485025/c2070-illegal-sizeof-operand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking at the "Error" window which (confusingly) only shows summaries. But double clicking that line should take you directly to the line with the problem.

Alternatively, View->Other Windows ->Output.  There's a LOT more to the error message, and this shows everything in all its incredible detail.

Comment: that's it, in `View->Other Windows ->Output` is the track back, thx alot